# How to install Oracle OCI header files for building things?

Tags: linux, oracle10g, instantclient, perl5.10

We have a web server running Oracle Enterprise Linux (OEL v6.8) which includes the Oracle HTTP Server (OHS; a customized version of Apache).  The OS has Perl v5.10.1 installed.  The database version we will connect to is Oracle v12.1.0.2.0.  Yes, I know these are all old but it's a legacy app and it's what I have to work with.

I'm trying to build the DBD::Oracle module and it fails.  Here is some of what it says:

```
Installing on a linux, Ver#3.8
Using Oracle in /mnt/ora_home/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1
DEFINE _SQLPLUS_RELEASE = "1201000200" (CHAR)
Oracle Version 12.1.0.2 (12.1)
Looks like an Instant Client installation, okay
Your LD_LIBRARY_PATH env var is set to '/mnt/ora_home/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1'

*********************************************************
I can't find the header files I need in your Oracle installation.
You probably need to install some more Oracle components.
For Instant Client that means the SDK package.
I'll keep going, but the compile will probably fail.
See the appropriate troubleshooting guide for your OS for more information.
*********************************************************
```

So I went to [this Oracle site](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html) and downloaded the devl rpm package (description is `SDK: Additional header files and an example makefile for developing Oracle applications with Instant Client`).  But when I attempt to install it (as root), it fails with:

```
Error: Package: oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64 (/oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64)
           Requires: oracle-instantclient12.1-basic >= 12.1.0.2.0
```

So, the module build process seems to detect an Instant Client installation, but the rpm install process does not.

Any suggestions on how to get the header files installed so that I can build the DBD::Oracle module?  Do I need a different install file for them?  Am I missing something simple?

Comment: The path `/mnt/ora_home/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1` looks like a "full" client (installed with the GUI installer), not Instant Client.  So the message when you install the devel RPM is expected.  However you probably don't need the devel package because the header files will  already be somewhere under `/mnt/ora_home/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1` - search for `oci.h` to confirm.  If the headers are there, then check you have ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH both set correctly.

Comment: @Christopher Jones - I have searched (as root) and the header files are not installed.

Comment: What's in /mnt/ora_home/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1 ?

Comment: Directory contents:  8 directories (```cfgtoollogs, install, inventory, jdbc, lib, light, network, nls, odbc```), 10 shared object files (```libheteroxa12.so, libipc1.so, libmql1.so, libnnz12.so, libociei.so, libocijdbc12.so, libons.so, liboramysql12.so, libsqlplusic.so, libsqlplus.so```), 4 jar files (```ojdbc6.jar, orai18n.jar, orai18n-mapping.jar, xstreams.jar```), 1 link (```libclntsh.so -> /mnt/ora_home/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_1/libclntsh.so.12.1```), 4 executables (```adrci, sqlplus, uidrvci, wrc), and 2 other files (oraInst.loc, tnsnames.ora```).

Comment: Whoops, missed 4 other .so files:  ```libclntshcore.so.12.1, libclntsh.so.12.1, libocci.so.12.1, libsqora.so.12.1```.   Sorry for the ugliness of the list!

Comment: Where did it come from?  Who installed it? Can they re-install with the header files? Do you need it?  If you don't need it, then install Instant Client Basic & SDK ZIP files.

Comment: The system (a web server and a database server) was created in 2018 by a contracted firm.  I ass-u-me that we need the current Oracle installation since we use OHS as the web server software with mod_plsql.  We no longer have a dedicated Oracle DBA which is why a software dev (me) is trying to figure this out.  There is a second perl installation that 'came with' the Oracle stuff and it has DBD::Oracle already built.  But I can't seem to use cpan to install other modules ("missing Config_heavy.pl").  Aaargghh!!  So frustrating.

Comment: OHS?  That explains why headers aren't there.  I once blogged about the setup.  FPM was one way, but later on OHS made even this difficult.  https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/installing-php-on-oracle-http-server-12c

Comment: That post is about PHP (I'm using Perl) but if I'm reading it right, the key part involving getting the headers is to install both the basic instant client and the devel package but not add it to ld.so.conf?  I can try that on the dev environment after having IT take a snap of the server 'just in case'.